# Assign category based on form used and dropdown

Tags: wordpress, frontend, categories

I have set up everything for adding posts from frontend, choosing categories, adding images, files.

A user can post from a form that automatically must have category, e.g. "small service".

I have several "main" categories e.g. "car", "motor". They all have "small service" as a  subcategory.

When a user chooses e.g. "car" from dropdown, Wordpress must automatically assign the post to category "car" and its subcategory "small service".

```
$postTitleError = '';

if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && isset($_POST['post_nonce_field']) && 
 wp_verify_nonce($_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce')) {

if(trim($_POST['postTitle']) === '') {
    $postTitleError = 'Molimo Vas da unesete naslov.';
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $postTitle = trim($_POST['postTitle']);
}
$cat_ID = get_cat_ID( $_POST['newcat'] );

//If not create new category
if($cat_ID == 0) {
   $cat_name = array('cat_name' => $_POST['newcat']);
   wp_insert_category($cat_name);
 }

  //Get ID of newly created category
 $new_cat_ID = get_cat_ID($_POST['newcat']);

$post_information = array(
    'post_title' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postTitle'])),
    'post_content' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postContent'])),
    'post-type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_category' => array($new_cat_ID)

);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_information);

if($post_id)
{

    // Update Custom Meta
update_post_meta($post_id, 'vsip_custom_date', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['customMetaDate'])));
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'vsip_custom_brojilo', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['customMetaBrojilo'])));
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'vsip_custom_ulje', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['customMetaUlje'])));
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'vsip_custom_filter', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['customMetaFilter'])));
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'vsip_custom_permant', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['customMetaPermant'])));
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'vsip_custom_zamjena', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['customMetaZamjena'])));
update_post_meta($post_id, 'vsip_custom_file', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['customMetaFile'])));

    // Redirect
    wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit;
 }

 } 
  ?>
 <?php
 if( ! empty( $_FILES ) ) {
 foreach( $_FILES as $file ) {
   if( is_array( $file ) ) {
     $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file );
   }
 }
 }
  ?>
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<!-- #primary BEGIN -->
 <div id="primary">
  <form action="" id="primaryPostForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
     <select id="cat" class="cat" name="newcat"  >
        <option value="0"><?php echo esc_attr(__('Izaberite vozilo')); ?></option>
        <?php
           $categories= get_categories(array('orderby ' => 'id' , 'order' => 'DESC' ,'hide_empty' => 0 , 'hierarchical' => true)); 
           foreach ($categories as $category) {
           $option = '<option value="'.$category->cat_name.', mali servis" broj="'.$category->category_count.'" val="'.$category->cat_name.'">';
           $option .= $category->cat_name; 
           $option .= '</option>';
           echo $option;
           }
           ?>
     </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
```

Comment: You can try multi dropdowns for category selection. In your first dropdown has only top categories. When user select any category, javascript add to document new dropdowns(if selected has subs). After post action, you can get all categories with hierarchy. And you can insert your posts to these. Is not that what you want?

Comment: The thing is it's little bit complicated. Boss and stuff... So I have all set up. I the only thing I need is assign this subcategory, maybe by name (they all have the same names), to parent that I choose from dropdown. So when I choose from dropdown category "car" wordpress can automatically assign ID from subcategory "small service" within category "car".